# What's the maximum possible power output of this RF CATV amp?

Tags: amplifier, rf, antenna, transmitter, ham-radio

please tell me what is the maximum possible output wattage that this RF CATV distribution amp (see below for specifications) would likely output with maximum possible input before damage?  ~13 mW is only for the amplification of the original signal, correct, but what would the absolute power in watts for all output irrespective of frequency (inclusive of all harmonics and distortions). Basically, from the 20W power consumption what is the maximum it could put out in Watts? could it output 3W or maybe 4W possibly? irrespective of usefulness of the signal. This is more of a power efficiency question, that is, from 20W power consumption what can it turn into RF and what will it turn to heat loss in watts?
Thank you so much,

amp specifications:
Input Frequency Range: 40 ~ 860 MHz
Output Max Level: 60 dBmV
Gain: 50 dB maximum
Gain Control Range: 0 ~ -18 dB adjustable
Tilt Control Range: 0 ~ -16 dB adjustable
Noise Figure: 7 dB
Flatness: +/- 2 dB
Input Return Loss: >13dB
Output Return Loss: >14dB
Input/ Output Impedance: 75 ohm
Input/ Output Test Port: - 20 dB
Dimension: 498mm (W) x 360mm (D) x 280mm (H)
Connectors: All F type female connectors
Internal AC Fuse: 1 Amp
Operating Temperature: 0 ~ 50 degree C
Power Supply: AC 110V +-10%
Power Consumption: 20W

Answer (score -1, accepted):

0 dBmV in 75 ohms is 13.3nW

60db is a million times greater: 13.3mW

820 Mhz is about 137 TV channels,
so about 1.8W  total.

Comment: WOW, thank you, so the answer is that from the 20W power input, there is a maximum possible power output in RF of 1.8W in total for the 137stations, but what about in total, irrespective of channels including the whole spectrum range of 820Mhz, would that be a lot more?

Comment: what is the maximum possible total transmitter power output of the CATV amp in Watts?

Comment: you coul maybe get another 20 to 30% if you filled in the gaps between stations with signal.

Comment: so ~2.5W in total transmitter power output in RF? so like ~85% loss to heat from the 20W power consumption?

Comment: I5% seems pretty good to me.  it's a linear amplifier, and probably class A so efficiency will be terrible before you figure in the typically poor performace of transistors above 20Mhz

Comment: Jasen, you wrote "I5%". what is that?  is that 15% or 5% or does i5% mean something?

Comment: fifteen percent